# How to detect error if archive of jar file failed?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, jar

I'm facing a problem where %errorlevel% return value of 0 even when archive of jar files failed.

What I'm trying to achieve is to archive log files in production environment. I use ROBOCOPY command to copy log files to a separated folder and try to archive those log files. "verify > nul" was used to reset the %errorlevel% back to 0 because the robocopy will set the value to 1 after execution.

However, when the error happened during the execution of jar command (i.e. no file to archive), %errorlevel% remain as 0 and program continue.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL

ECHO [info] LogFileArchivaer Started at time %date% %time% ...
SET LOG_FILE_AGE_IN_DAY=7

REM Directory variable setting
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G IN (config.properties) DO (

    IF "%%G"=="log.app.dir.ori" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET APP_LOG_DIR_ORI=%%H
    )

    IF "%%G"=="log.server.dir.ori" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET SERVER_LOG_DIR_ORI=%%H
    )
    IF "%%G"=="log.batch.dir.ori" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET BATCH_LOG_DIR_ORI=%%H
    )
    IF "%%G"=="log.app.dir.dest" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET APP_LOG_DIR_DEST=%%H
    )
    IF "%%G"=="log.server.dir.dest" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET SERVER_LOG_DIR_DEST=%%H
    )
    IF "%%G"=="log.batch.dir.dest" (
        IF NOT EXIST %%H\NUL (
            ECHO [error] Directory "%%H" not exist!
            GOTO ERROR
        )
        SET BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST=%%H
    )
    IF "%%G"=="log.file.age" (
        SET /a LOG_FILE_AGE_IN_DAY="%%H"*1
    )
)

REM Prepare formatted system date
SET year=%date:~-4%

SET month=%date:~3,2%
IF "%month:~0,1%" == " " SET month=0%month:~1,1%

SET day=%date:~0,2%
IF "%day:~0,1%" == " " SET day=0%day:~1,1%

SET hour=%time:~0,2%
IF "%hour:~0,1%" == " " SET hour=0%hour:~1,1%

SET min=%time:~3,2%
IF "%min:~0,1%" == " " SET min=0%min:~1,1%

SET datetime_formatted=%year%%month%%day%_%hour%%min%

ECHO [info] Age of log files to be archived: [%LOG_FILE_AGE_IN_DAY%] days.

ECHO [info] === Processing batch job log files ===

ROBOCOPY %BATCH_LOG_DIR_ORI% %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST% *.log /MINAGE:%LOG_FILE_AGE_IN_DAY%
IF %errorlevel% GEQ 2 GOTO ERROR

REM Reset the errorLevel value back to 0
verify > nul

IF exist %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST%*.log (
    CD %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST%
    jar -cvMf %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST%batch_job_log_%datetime_formatted%.zip *.log

    IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR

    FOR /F %%J IN ('dir /b /A-D %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST%*.log') DO (
        ECHO [info] Deleting file: %%J
        DEL %BATCH_LOG_DIR_DEST%%%J
        DEL %BATCH_LOG_DIR_ORI%%%J
        IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO [info] No batch log file to process.
)

ECHO [info] === Batch job log files archived completed ===

GOTO COMPLETED

:ERROR
ECHO [error] Error Occurred, program exit at time %date% %time%!    
GOTO END

:COMPLETED
ECHO [info] LogFileArchivaer Completed at time %date% %time% ...    
GOTO END

:END
```

Note: Varible are read from properties file. 3rd party library were not allowed to install, therefore I choose to use the jar command

Any hint how to detect if error occurred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to David method *(**use delayed expansion**)* which I support +1, you might use the **`if errorlevel` command** instead. I'd do.

```
if errorlevel 1 goto error
```

Read this Raymond Chen entry **ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx in *The Old New Thing* blog.

And then try this excerpts..

```
robocopy %ORI% %DEST% *.log ....
if errorlevel 2 goto error
...
if exist *.log ( 
   jar -cvMf ..
   if errorlevel 1 goto error
   for %%a in *.log do (
     del %%a ....
     if errorlevel 1 goto error
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as the use of ERRORLEVEL instead of variable %errorlevel% does address my problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Use Delayed Expansion

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
...
    IF !errorlevel! NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR
```

Make sure to do this for all variables within parentheses scopes that are modified within the scope.

Whenever expanding variables inside a parenthetical scope `()`, the variables will be expanded to their values as they were before the scope began, unless expanded with Delayed Expansion or a workaround.

### Illustration

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "x=0"
echo %x%

if 1==1 (
    set "x=1"
    echo %x%
)
endlocal
```