# Detecting failure of JAR command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, jar, error-detection

I am executing this simple `jar` command in bash:

```
jar cvfm control.jar Manifest <class list>
```

How can I automate the detection of a failure in the execution of this command? 
By failure i mean that the command just simply failed to execute due reasons such as:

- an error in the `Manifest`,
- improper usage of the `jar` command itself,
- some random error like, `ClassNotFoundError`, etc.

Mind you, I am **not** interested in knowing if the right set of classes were archived or not. So I will not consider that to be a failure.

I am currently just using the verbose option to inspect if everything went well or not. But, I find this to be time consuming. I just want to know whether or not the `jar` command was successful in archiving some set of class files or not. Is there a way to do this in bash?

---

the closest other resource regarding this issue i found was this: [How to detect error if archive of jar file failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199947/how-to-detect-error-if-archive-of-jar-file-failed). But, i have no clue about batch files and i am interested in doing this in the bash shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most basic way to see if a command suceeded:

```
if jar cvfm control.jar Manifest <class list> ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Oops!"
fi
```

If you only want to detect failure, then invert the test:

```
if ! jar cvfm control.jar Manifest <class list> ; then
    echo "Oops!"
fi
```

Or test the result explicitly:

```
jar cvfm control.jar Manifest <class list>
if (( $? )) ; then
    echo "Oops!"
fi
```

Comment: will the `if (( $? )) ; then` condition hold for only the most recently executed command or any command that was executed before this condition was checked?

Comment: ignore the previous comment... figured it out ... :)

Comment: Only the most recent. In fact the `(( $? ))` itself changes $?. If you need it to persist you have to assign it to a variable immediately after the command you want to track: `result=$?`

Comment: ah ...  interesting point about `(( $? ))` changing `$?` ... thanks for the answer as well.

Comment: Pretty much everything changes $? :-)